# Convert .CSV |-separated file to .xlsx file

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a .CSV file that is generated every day that opens in an Excel workbook. It is separated by | character like this:

```
0-1-C|COUTEAU À HUITRE RICHARD|||||40|5,99|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2,65|
 0000|ARTICLEVENTEFINALEdémonstrateur|||||945|9999,99|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|||||
00007|SUPER DÉTACHANT OOPS!|||SUPER DÉTACHANT||100|3,99|
```

Each line of the text above is in the first cell of a line .I'd like to generate a version of this file in another Excel workbook that uses one cell per string between |. The file is about 6200 lines long and since its generated everyday, I need it to juste loop over every line and create a new one in the document. I'm very new to VBA and and this website so p-lease be patient with me, thank you very much !

Comment: This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this sub

```
Sub main()

    Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns , , , , , , , , True, "|"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you very much !